# Importing "rtmidi_python" module gives "ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found"

Tags: python, windows, dll, pip, importerror

I have run into an issue when trying to import rtmidi-python *(link to package index page excised due to lacking reputation)*:

```
    Python 3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  6 2015, 01:38:48) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import rtmidi_python
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import rtmidi_python
ImportError: DLL load failed: Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden.
```

"Das angegebene Modul wurde nicht gefunden" translates as "The specified module could not be found."

The packages was installed from the *.whl* file found on http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/, to circumvent the necessity of having a working C/C++ compiler (as far as I understand), since installing the package from the index through pip would invariably give me the *"vcvarsall.bat"* error.
(Something which I've tried to fix in a variety of ways without success, but detailing this would not be within the topic of this thread.)

I resorted to using the .whl files as a result.
Since I work on **Windows 7 32-bit**, with **Python 3.5.1 32-bit** installed, I used  *"rtmidi_python-0.2.2-cp35-none-win32.whl"* to make a pip install. That seemed to work, and the package was apparently installed. But when trying to *import rtmidi_python*, I would invariably give me the error above.

- I've tried reinstalling the package from the wheel several times, to no avail. The same error would come up every time.
- I've tried upgrading the package through pip, but it was up-to-date.
- Since according to my findings on this site and elsewhere, *ImportError* is not a general error, but has a specific and different cause in every instance; I've tried to track down what specific .dll file might be missing. Since installing rtmidi-python through the .whl only places within *"...\site-packages\"* the usual *"...dist-info"* folder (as *"rtmidi_python-0.2.2.dist-info"*) and a .pyd file called *"rtmidi_python.cp35-win32.pyd"*, I assume the later was the cause of the issue. After a bit of search I discovered such a file could be examined using the **Dependency Walker**. Here is what came up:

[Click this link to see a screenshot.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l8zJ4.png)

"Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden." translates literally as "The system can not find the specified file."
At first I assumed, disregarding the other files, that MSVCP140.DLL referred to a file that would install with Visual Studio 2015 or somesuch, which I do not have installed. But after having explorer search for it, MSVCP140.DLL is found as *"msvcp140.dll"* in *"...\system32\"*.

Does that mean the error stems from rtmidi_python not being given the right path for these files? Or that I somehow misinstalled some files relating to C/C++ compilers while trying to fix the "vcvarsall.bat" error?
Or might the issue lie with the .whl itself? I read on some pages documenting similar ImportErrors that it could stem from erroneous compiling on the part of the creator of the wheel file.

Either way, I have arrived at a point of complete loss of what else to do but ask for help here. Moreso because, as is my own case, this package might be very useful to non-programmers wanting to benefit from it for musical purposes, and I think it would be good thing to make it more easily accessible and usable.

If I have by accident omitted any information essential to solving the issue, I will provide it as needed.

Comment: Install the 32-bit (x86) version of the [Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48145)

Comment: This does indeed solve the issue! But to clarify an important aspect of it: The Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015 needs to be installed BEFORE installing rtmidi-python as a .whl. So, even if both are installed, but one installed the Redistributable after installing rtmidi-python, it will not work. I can not tell for sure since I tried many things, but if the opposite was done, even a mere reinstall of rtmidi-python might not work.
In my case, I needed to uninstall both, then reinstall the Redistributable; finishing with a fresh installation of rtmidi-python.